# Sencha Touch/Modern Hide Address Bar and/or Bottom Bar

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch/ExtJs 6 Modern is there a way to hide the address bar and bottom bar on mobile devices. I have tried this which was suggested and it doesn't work.

```
Ext.application({

    viewport: {
      autoMaximize: true
    },

    ...
});
```

Comment: Are you actually deploying your app. to the device?  It sounds like you're just viewing it like a web app. on a server through a web-browser - in which case, no it's unlikely you will be able to manipulate features of the browser itself.

Comment: Please try to create a phonegap application and use your code in there. This will help you solve your problem.